# How can i create a class without an option to create its object in php

Tags: php, class, object

How can i create a class without an option to create its object in  php.
    Is there any option for this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean [abstract classes?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

> PHP 5 introduces abstract classes and methods. Classes defined as abstract may not be instantiated, and any class that contains at least one abstract method must also be abstract. Methods defined as abstract simply declare the method's signature - they cannot define the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You may use abstract classes (as Pekka mentioned in his answer) or build it as static class and deny its creation in constructor manually:

```
class NotToBeInstantializes {
  public function __construct(){
    throw new Exception( 'Cannot create object from this class!');
  }
}
```

Comment: could also make it `final private`